# How to handle a testing commit in git?

Tags: git, testing

I have a commit that helps with testing my program (i.e. stopping the application from being topmost).
Now I want to be able to apply this commit at whatever place I am currently at, when I need to test something.

I have tried to achieve this with creating a `testing` branch and rebasing that to my current HEAD whenever I need it. But this always results in problems and seems not to be the way to do this.

Comment: My assumption is you want to, when you are done "testing", remove the code that the commit put into place so that the code is no longer in your project going forward?

Comment: I don't really think this is what Git is designed to do. You'd probably have better luck keeping the testing code in a text file or a script in the repository and copying it over (you can script this) when you need to test. Then you can revert the changes when you are done testing.

Comment: @MarkHildreth yes, I want to do that.

Comment: Even better if you implement just a toggle in your program for enabling the test mode.

Comment: I agree with what Issac and Slaven said: keep the debug code in your code, and have a toggle (such as only running the debug code when in debug mode or making the debug mode part of a configuration file). You could cherry-pick a git commit, but it just seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played around a bit with `git cherry-pick` and it seems to be possible to do this with it.

If the changes needed for testing are all contained in one commit you can create a branch or tag at that commit. Lets name it `testing`.

```
git cherry-pick -n testing
```

will apply this commit to your current working directory and your index. It would be great if it wouldn't be applied to the index as well, but I haven't seen a way to do this yet.

So after testing you have to do

```
git reset --hard
```

to get back to where you were before testing.

If the changes for testing are scattered over more than 1 commit, but all those commits are in a separate branch called `testing`, then we need to know the point where the `testing` commits started. That is usually master, but if it is not you can create a tag at that commit and name it something like `testingStart`. In this case replace `master` with `testingStart` in the following commands:

```
git cherry-pick -n testing ^master
```

This picks all commits that are in the testing branch, but not in the master branch. Therefore it is not necessary that the HEAD of the master branch points to the startpoint of the testing branch. It just has to include that startpoint in its history.

After testing do

```
git reset --hard
```

as above.

If you forgot the `-n` in one of the cherry-pick commands above you can use

```
git branch -f <commit>
```

to move the branch you applied the testing commits to back to the state it was in before that. Just make sure to select the correct commit.

Answer (score 2):

I managed something similar (adding some new debugging classes to separate files, changing some interceptors to log stuff / increasing logging levels / etc) with patches.

Take a look at [git-format-patch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html), [git-apply](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html) and [git-am](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) commands.

The workflow goes like this:

Generate your *testing* patch (you will only need to do this one time, unless commits in your branch breaks the patch).

```
# switch to the testing branch
git checkout testing
# Generate the patch against the desired branch
git format-patch master --stdout > test_helper.patch
```

When you need the helper code, just apply the script over your branch

```
# check if patch can be applied
git apply --check test_helper.patch
# apply the patch
git apply --v test_helper.patch
```

Debbug your code.

When you are done just throw away uncommitted changes

```
# revert changes to modified files.
git reset --hard   
# remove all untracked files and directories.
git clean -fd
```